# how to copy AMI from one aws account to other aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

Am trying to copy the custom built ami using packer from one AWS account to another AWS account; however, i was able to copy ami across regions within one account.

`"builders": [{
    "account_id": "12345678910",
    "s3_bucket": "xyz/xqas/asd",
    "x509_cert_path": "/Users/txyz/packer/certificate.pem",
    "x509_key_path": "/Users/txyz/packer/private-key.pem",
    "type": "amazon-instance",
    "access_key": "{{user`access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user`secret_key`}}",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "source_ami": "ami-452bd728",
    "instance_type": "r3.xlarge",
    "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
    "ami_name": "packer-test-hvm {{timestamp}}",
    "ami_virtualization_type": "hvm",
    "force_deregister": true,
    "ami_regions": ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]
  }],`

Comment: I have other account details.. !

Comment: It is easy through AWS dashboard

Comment: i want the task automated via cli , how about ami_users.... any on tried using tat ?

Comment: Yes you just need write a script that will run this command aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-2bb65342 --launch-permission "{\"Add\":[{\"UserId\":\"123456789012\"}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AWS ClI and run the following command in the AMI that needs to be transferred

```
ec2-modify-image-attribute ami-2bb65342 -l -a 111122223333
```

For other options that are available please refer this guide

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html

Comment: can this be pushed inside packer provisioner  as inline command ?!

Comment: Unfortunately no Only 3 options AWS Dashboard, EC2 Cli and AWS CLI

Comment: "ami_users": ["account1", "account2"]       from packer helped..
More than copying to the other accounts, sharing is possible as private AMIs.

Comment: Those options (``-l`` , ``-a`` ) are not valid. Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-image-attribute.html

Answer (score 0):

The following awscli command will add launch permissions to a specified account id. This achieves a similar effect although does not technically copy the ami over.

`aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id <image id> --launch-permission "Add=[{UserId=<account-id>}]"`

Answer (score 0):

Using Packer this is the way you can share the AMIs from one account to the other.
Always refer the Packer docs:-https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs  here you can find all the information.

in the "ami_users" section you can mention the AWS accounts you need to share with.

```
"ami_users": ["{{user `REMOTE_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`}}"]
```

**full code**

```
   "builders": [
  {
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "access_key": "{{ user `aws_access_key` }}",
    "secret_key": "{{ user `aws_secret_key` }}",
    "region": "{{ user `region` }}",
    "launch_block_device_mappings" : [
        {
           "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
           "volume_size": 60
        }
      ],
    "instance_type": "t2.large",
    "ami_users": "{{ user `REMOTE_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` }}",
    "source_ami": "{{ user `source_ami` }}",
    "ami_name": "xyz-ami",
    "user_data_file": "./bootstrap_win.txt",
    "communicator": "winrm",
    "winrm_username": "Administrator",
    "winrm_password": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "tags": [{"Name":"testing","release":"packer"}],
    "ami_regions": [
      "ap-southeast-2",
      "us-east-2"
    ]
  }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to move the AMI from Account A to Account B,  then you can use AWS CLI to do it.

Assume you already set the 2 AWS account credential.

```
#  cat ~/.aws/credentials
[account_a]
aws_access_key_id = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

[account_b]
aws_access_key_id = bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then using the `account_a` run the command below to build an image (AMI) from a running instance:   (you can skip this step if you already have an AMI)

```
# aws ec2 create-image --profile account_a --region $region --instance-id i-0aaaaaaaaaaaaa1 --name "image_name_here" --no-reboot
```

Share the AMI from `account_a` to `account_b`

```
# aws ec2 --profile account_a --region $region modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-aaaaaaaaaaa --launch-permission "Add=[{UserId=$account_b_id}]"
```

Use `account_b` to see if you get the shared AMI from `account_a`

```
# aws ec2 describe-images --profile account_b --region $region --executable-users self
```

The output should show if you get the shared AMI, or you also can go to AWS EC2 console, click `Images` --> `AMIs`,  then change the `Owned by me` to `Prviate images`,  you should be able to see the shared image as well.

extra:

if you want to launch an instance from the shared AMI on `account_b`

```
# aws ec2 run-instances --profile account_b --region $region --image-id ami-aaaaaaaaaaaaa --instance-type t2.micro --key-name $key_pair_for_access_ec2
```

Don't forget to edit the security group inbound rule for the SSH port open